# Good sshd + unix environment for Windows needed

Tags: windows, unix, remote

My job is 95% Unix administration, but sometimes I manage Windows machines remotely.  While I'm familiar enough with VNC and RDP solutions, there are times when I'd like something a little more lightweight for bandwidth reasons, as well as having a more familiar scripting environment and tool set.

I know there are several Unix layers for the Windows platform e.g. cygwin, uwin, WSU, and there are a handful of sshd servers.  However, I'm not sure which ones give the most "unix-like" console experience, in terms of shells and standard utilities e.g. ps, top, tcpdump.  Do these environments allow one to run the normal, stock command line utilities such as net, ipconfig, fsutil as well?

Any experiences, advice and hints welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the most Unix-like console experience, I'd definitely use [OpenSSH with Cygwin](http://lifehacker.com/205090/geek-to-live--set-up-a-personal-home-ssh-server). This way, all of your Windows commands are available, as well as your Unix commands.

Installing OpenSSH with Cygwin is a breeze. Simply check off the OpenSSH box under the Net section when choosing packages:

[image]

After setup, run `ssh-host-config` in Cygwin. It will ask you various questions:

- privilege separation - answer **yes**
- create a local sshd user - answer **yes**
- install sshd as a service - answer **yes**
- Your cygwin tty (CYGWIN=) - answer **ntsec tty**

Now open `c:\cygwin\etc\defaults\etc\sshd_config`.

Change `#Protocol 2,1` to `Protocol 2` for security reasons.

Now you can start the sshd service. Go to **Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services** and start Cygwin sshd:

[image]

you'll want to set the service to start automatically so it persists across reboots.

If you're using the Windows firewall, add an exception on port 22:

[image]

For a console, I'd highly recommend [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) to connect remotely.

Comment: Voted for a great, succinct primer.  I'm still fine-tuning the install.  I'll see if I can get what I need.

Comment: @Geoff, @John: i've just run through this on my system with the latest cygwin 1.7.x.  i don't believe the step editing */etc/defaults/etc/sshd_config* is necessary; in particular this file is a default file, while */etc/sshd_config* should be the one used by the daemon.  the recommended change no longer seems necessary; the default value of that line is now `#Protocol 2` and you'd have to explicitly change that to allow protocol 1.  (otherwise, good tips, thanks!)